# How to show the current position of a tree node

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, tree

I have a tree structure implementation that looks like this:

```
class Node {

    let value: String

    var parentNode: Node?
    var childenNode = [Node]()

    func appendNode(node: Node) {
        childenNode.append(node)
        node.parentNode = self.parentNode
    }

    func isLeaveNode(node: Node) -> Bool{
        if node.childenNode.isEmpty {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

I want to have a function that returns back the path it took to get to the current node. For example: say I have a leave node `node` and the path it took to get to that leave node is say `Main Menu -> Setting -> User Options -> Set User Options`, then I want a function that returns that path: E.g. `func path(node: Node) -> path`. How do I implement that?

I have tried using a `for-in` loop to loop through the parent node. However, since `Node` is not conformed to `sequence` protocol, that cannot be done.

Thanks heaps! any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just loop back to parent nodes until the parent node is nil

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but since node is not conformed to `sequence` protocol, that is impossible

Comment: try something like this:
`func path(node: Node) -> [Node] { return path.parentNode == nil ? [self] : path(node: parentNode!) + [self] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that recursively iterates through the nodes using `parentNode` until it reaches the root like this:

```
func getPath()->[Node]{
    return self.parentNode == nil ? [self] : [self] + self.parentNode!.getPath()
}
```

I tested it using the following example:

```
let grandParent = Node(value: "grand")
let parent = Node(value: "parent")
parent.parentNode = grandParent
let child = Node(value: "child")
child.parentNode = parent
child.getPath() //returns [grandParent, parent, child]
```

The ternary operator in the function is just shorthand for

```
func getPath()->[Node]{
    if self.parentNode == nil {
        return [self]
    } else {
        return [self] + self.parentNode!.getPath() //this is the recursive call
    }
}
```

`self.parentNode == nil` means that we found the root node, so this is the base case of the recursive call, we just have to return the current value. If `self.parentNode != nil`, it means that we are at a child node, so the return value will be an array of the current node + the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, but I want to understand your code better, can you re-write code so that it is not in one line? thanks much

Comment: @BrendonCheung I explained it in more detail, but this is the beauty of recursion, you can write really simple call. The ternary operator saves some lines, but even without that the function is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

If recursion is new for you, you can also try iterative approach. Following David's answer.

```
func getPath() -> [Node] {
  var currentNode = self
  var path: [Node] = []
  while currentNode != nil {
    path += [currentNode]
    currentNode = currentNode.parentNode
  }
  return path
}
```